# How to split Strings of a text file into char and number in python

Tags: python

I'm having a file that contains strings like this :

```
N1109 X62.729 Y23.764 Z231.442 A59.756 B9.231
```

So I want to split char and integers from this file. The output should me like this :

```
N 1109  X 62.729 Y 23.764 Z 231.442  A 59.756 B 9.231
```

This is in a text file. I dont know how to do this from a text file.

code that I've wrote for this is :

```
import re
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
f = open(filename,"r")
lines = f.readlines()
print lines
r = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)")
a = [r.match(string).group() for string in lines]
print a
```

When I use `group()` I got this error :

```
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`
```

and when i remove `group()` the output is :

`[<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb72f1b18>, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]`

Please help me I'm new in python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re` module for this purpose.

Try this, this may help you.

```
import re
>>> match = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", 'N1109', re.I)
>>> if match:
        print match.groups()

Output:

('N', '1109')
```

**Update**

```
>>> a=['N1109', 'X62.729', 'Y23.764', 'Z231.442', 'A59.756', 'B9.231']
>>> answer=[]
>>> for i in a:
        match = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)", i, re.I)
            if match:
                   answer.append(match.groups())


>>> answer
[('N', '1109'), ('X', '62.729'), ('Y', '23.764'), ('Z', '231.442'), ('A', '59.756'), ('B', '9.231')]
>>>
```

### **Update**

```
>>> with open(r'd:\test1.txt') as f:
         content = f.readlines()       
>>> content=' '.join(content)
>>> content=content.split()
>>> answer=[]
>>> for i in content:
         match = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)", i, re.I)
                if match:
                    answer.append(match.groups())


>>> answer
[('N', '1100'), ('X', '63.658'), ('Y', '21.066'), ('Z', '230.989'), ('A', '60.28'), ('B', '9.5'), ('N', '1101'), ('X', '63.424'), ('Y', '21.419'), ('Z', '231.06'), ('A', '60.269'), ('B', '9.459'), ('N', '1102'), ('X', '63.219'), ('Y', '21.805'), ('Z', '231.132'), ('A', '60.231'), ('B', '9.418'), ('N', '1103'), ('X', '63.051'), ('Y', '22.206'), ('Z', '231.202'), ('A', '60.169'), ('B', '9.377'), ('N', '1104'), ('X', '62.915'), ('Y', '22.63'), ('Z', '231.272'), ('A', '60.083'), ('B', '9.335'), ('N', '1105'), ('X', '62.863'), ('Y', '22.851'), ('Z', '231.307'), ('A', '60.027'), ('B', '9.314'), ('N', '1106'), ('X', '62.811'), ('Y', '23.073'), ('Z', '231.341'), ('A', '59.971'), ('B', '9.293'), ('N', '1111'), ('X', '62.702'), ('Y', '24.227'), ('Z', '231.506'), ('A', '59.596'), ('B', '9.191'), ('N', '1112'), ('X', '62.71'), ('Y', '24.462'), ('Z', '231.536'), ('A', '59.503'), ('B', '9.172'), ('N', '1113'), ('X', '62.718'), ('Y', '24.697'), ('Z', '231.567'), ('A', '59.41'), ('B', '9.152'), ('N', '1114'), ('X', '62.727'), ('Y', '24.932'), ('Z', '231.597'), ('A', '59.316'), ('B', '9.133'), ('N', '1115'), ('X', '62.734'), ('Y', '25.167'), ('Z', '231.627'), ('A', '59.222'), ('B', '9.114'), ('N', '1123'), ('X', '62.793'), ('Y', '27.037'), ('Z', '231.864'), ('A', '58.46'), ('B', '8.961')]
>>>
```

Comment: This is good and working for particular strings. But how to do it for a complete file. I have only file name and its location.

Comment: @user3125133 Can you please provide sample of text file do u have

Comment: N1100 X63.658 Y21.066 Z230.989 A60.28 B9.5
N1101 X63.424 Y21.419 Z231.06 A60.269 B9.459
N1102 X63.219 Y21.805 Z231.132 A60.231 B9.418
N1103 X63.051 Y22.206 Z231.202 A60.169 B9.377
N1104 X62.915 Y22.63 Z231.272 A60.083 B9.335
N1105 X62.863 Y22.851 Z231.307 A60.027 B9.314
N1106 X62.811 Y23.073 Z231.341 A59.971 B9.293
N1111 X62.702 Y24.227 Z231.506 A59.596 B9.191
N1112 X62.71 Y24.462 Z231.536 A59.503 B9.172
N1113 X62.718 Y24.697 Z231.567 A59.41 B9.152
N1114 X62.727 Y24.932 Z231.597 A59.316 B9.133
N1115 X62.734 Y25.167 Z231.627 A59.222 B9.114
N1123 X62.793 Y27.037 Z231.864 A58.46 B8.961

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `match` will only search from the beginning, and then stop:

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the
>   regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject
>   instance.

You need to use `findall`:

```
>>> i
'N1109   X62.729   Y23.764   Z231.442   A59.756   B9.231'
>>> re.findall(r'(\w{1})(\d+\.?\d+)', i)
[('N', '1109'), ('X', '62.729'), ('Y', '23.764'), ('Z', '231.442'), ('A', '59.756'), ('B', '9.231')]
```

Also, consider using the `with` statement, which will handle closing of files for you:

```
import re
import sys

exp = r'(\w{1})(\d+\.?\d+)'

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        for letter,number in re.findall(exp, line):
            print('{} {}'.format(letter, number))
```

In addition, your original expression `"([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)"` did not take into account the optional `.` part of the number - your expression is *"one or more alphabetical character, irrespective of case followed by one or more digit"*, the expression you need is *"one or more alphabetical character, followed by one or more numbers, an optional `.`, and then one or more numbers"*.